# Issue with Joint tables in mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

When I use this query, I get notice error for my variables in my array - if I use $author_slug = $row['slug']; instead of $author_slug = $row['authors.slug']; it works but how would I know which data is from which table?

```
$select_quote=mysql_query("SELECT authors.name, authors.id, authors.img, authors.slug, quotes.author_id, quotes.title, quotes.id, quotes.meta_keys, quotes.meta_description, quotes.slug, quotes.content
                           from quotes, authors
                           WHERE quotes.author_id = authors.id
                       ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ");

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($select_quote)) {

    $author_id = $row['authors.id'];
    $author_name = $row['authors.name'];
    $author_slug = $row['authors.slug'];

    echo" $author_slug";
    }
```

Comment: `var_dump($row)` will answer all of your questions. Plus, realize that `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated/obsolete and shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aliases for this fields :

```
SELECT authors.name
     , authors.id
     , authors.img
     , authors.slug AS 'authors.slug'
     , quotes.author_id
     , quotes.title
     , quotes.id
     , quotes.meta_keys
     , quotes.meta_description
     , quotes.slug AS 'quotes.slug'
     , quotes.content
 FROM quotes, authors
 WHERE quotes.author_id = authors.id
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

So you can access retrieved data in php like :

```
 $author_slug = $row['authors.slug']
 $quotes_slug = $row['quotes.slug']
```

Comment: I should say, you are a hero :) Thanks dude